# Prevent Console Return

Tags: vb.net, winforms, command-line

Can a VB.NET Windows Forms Application be configured so that when run from the command-line, the command-line waits until the application exits before showing the next prompt?

Comment: AFAIK, it does work by this way, without any changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the command to start your application from the command line to:

```
start /wait YourApplication.exe
```

In general the command line behavior depends on the subsystem your application is using (Console/Windows). As an Application with the subsystem Windows doesn't have standard input/output streams, there is no need for the console to wait for them.

But you can change your application to be a console app and use your existing forms as usual. This [link](http://expsharing.blogspot.com/2008/03/hideshow-console-window-in-net-black.html) shows an example.

Answer (score 1):

The code after Application.Run(new Form1()); is only run after the application has been exited. No configuration needed.

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        string s = "test string";
        s.Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is No, but a console application can show forms.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the command-line is your own console app, then no.

I suppose you could create a console app that shelled out to the windows forms app... a bootstrapper of sorts.  If the console app were to be launched by command-line, it might do the trick.